# Sophos Threat "Adware or PUA" on Mac

Tags: macos

I was downloading a camera user manual on the Mac and Sophos threat manager indicated Generic PUA. I tried to automatically clean it up but the message came back that it required manual cleanup. What are the steps required to clean up the following location:

/Volumes/Installer/Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/AppYM

Answer (score 1):

It's just a disk image containing Adware. Unmount it and delete the disk image, if you didn't open the app.